# Cached-resources plugin is not working?

Tags: grails

I'm using cached-resources plugin in my Grails project, but every time I refresh page with F5 it reloads resources with http response code 200 instead of 304. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 2):

Solved this problem by overriding some methods in *cached-resources-1.0* and *cache-headers-1.1.5* plugins. 
Take a look at his plugins.
 
Pay attantion at **CacheHeadersService** in *cache-headers* plugin, **void cache(response, Map args)** method, instead of it I add dynamicly **void cache(req,response, Map args)** method (see the class below) wich looks at request headers and send 304 if resource is cached by browser.
And also **HashAndCacheResourceMapper** in *cached-resources* plugin, method **def map(resource, config)** wich I override to use my ne method from **CacheHeadersService**.

In BootStrap run method **void cacheResources(GrailsApplication application)** to apply changes to your project.

```
class CustomCachedResourcesProcessor {

public static void cacheResources(GrailsApplication application){
    addMethodsToMapResources(application)
    application.mainContext.grailsResourceProcessor.reloadAll()
}

private static void addMethodsToMapResources(GrailsApplication application){
    addCacheMethod()
    application.getClassForName("org.grails.plugin.cachedresources.HashAndCacheResourceMapper").metaClass.map{resource, config->
        if (log.debugEnabled) {
            log.debug "Hashing resources to unique names..."
        }

        resource.processedFile = renameToHashOfContents(resource.processedFile, resource.processedFileExtension)
        resource.updateActualUrlFromProcessedFile()

        // Do all the horrible cache header stuff
        resource.requestProcessors << { req, resp ->
            if (log.debugEnabled) {
                log.debug "Setting caching headers on ${req.requestURI}"
            }
            cacheHeadersService.cache(req,resp, [neverExpires: true, shared: true])
        }
    }
}

private static void addCacheMethod(){
    CacheHeadersService.metaClass.cache{request,response, Map args->
        if (!enabled) {
            return
        }
        def store = args.store
        def share = args.shared
        def validFor = args.validFor
        def validUntil = args.validUntil
        def neverExpires = args.neverExpires
        def requiresAuth = args.auth

        def now = new Date()

        def expiresOn
        def maxage
        if (validFor != null) {
            expiresOn = new Date(now.time + validFor*1000L)
            maxage = Math.max(0, validFor)
        } else if (validUntil != null) {
            expiresOn = validUntil
            maxage = Math.round( Math.max(0, validUntil.time-now.time) / 1000L)
        } else if (neverExpires) {
            // HTTP 1.1 spec says SHOULD NOT set more than 1 yr in future
            // @todo Investigate if impls of servletresponse.setDateHeader() are using efficient threadlocals,
            // and if so change to use those
            expiresOn = now + 365
            maxage = Math.round( Math.max(0, expiresOn.time-now.time) / 1000L)
        }

        def cacheControl = []

        // Now set the headers
        if ((store != null) && !store) {
            cacheControl << 'no-store'
        }

        // Always set private if no explicit share - help grails devs by defaulting to safest
        if (share) {
            cacheControl << 'public'
            // Note, for authentication sites we still need to add no-cache to force verification
            // to which the app can return "not modified" if it handles etag/lastmod
            if (requiresAuth) {
                cacheControl <<  'no-cache'
            }
        } else {
            cacheControl << 'private'
        }

        if (maxage != null) {
            if (share) {
                cacheControl << "s-maxage=$maxage"
            }
            // Always set max-age anyway, even if shared. Browsers may not pick up on s-maxage
            cacheControl << "max-age=$maxage"
        }

        if (cacheControl) {
            response.setHeader('Cache-Control', cacheControl.join(', '))
        }

        if (expiresOn != null) {
            response.setDateHeader('Expires', expiresOn.time)
        }

        def possibleTags = request.getHeader('If-None-Match')
        def modifiedDate = -1
        try {
            modifiedDate = request.getDateHeader('If-Modified-Since')
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            log.error ("Couldn't parse If-Modified-Since header", iae)
        }

        def lastModChanged = false

        if (possibleTags || (modifiedDate != -1)) {
            if (modifiedDate != -1) {
                def compareDate = new Date(modifiedDate)
                if (compareDate > now) {
                    lastModChanged = true
                }
            }

            if (!lastModChanged) {
                response.sendError(304) // Not modified
                return false
            }
        }

        // Always set last modified for courtesy and older clients,
        // only if not already set by application (load balancers need identical lastmods)
        if (!response.containsHeader('Last-Modified')) {
            lastModified(response, now)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know what do you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

I added same code, but not working.
I am using
Grails 2.1.4
Groovy 2.0.4
apache-tomcat-7.0.37
jdk 1.7
Windows 7

And in Config.groovy

```
// changed
grails.resources.modules = {
    'core' {
        defaultBundle 'core-ui'
        resource url: '/css/cisco_base.css', attrs: [ media: 'screen' ]
        resource url: '/css/cl.min.css', attrs: [ media: 'screen' ]
        resource url: '/css/errors.css', attrs: [ media: 'screen' ]
        resource url: '/css/jquery.multiselect.css', attrs: [ media: 'screen' ]
        resource url: '/css/main.css', attrs: [ media: 'screen' ]
        resource url: '/css/masterbrand.min.css', attrs: [ media: 'screen' ]
        resource url: '/css/mcd.min.css', attrs: [ media: 'screen' ]
        resource url: '/css/mobile.css', attrs: [ media: 'screen' ]
        resource url: '/css/Sampleapp.css', attrs: [ media: 'screen' ]
        resource url: '/css/style.css', attrs: [ media: 'screen' ]
        resource url: '/css/table.css', attrs: [ media: 'screen' ]
        wrapper: { s -> "<!--[if lt IE 8]>$s<![endif]-->"

        }
        //resource url: '/css/all.css', attrs: [ media: 'screen' ]
        //resource url: '/css/lt7.css', attrs: [ media: 'screen' ],
    }

    'ui' {
        defaultBundle 'core-ui'
        resource url: '/js/SampleApp.js', disposition: 'head'
    }
}
// changed
```

And I got your code(above) and placed in
src/groovy/com.sample.resources.

```
I am testing like this,
1.  With my changes I am creating a war file with maven package.
2.  Deploying in tomcat.
3.  Open browser and login  to SampleGrailsApp(just open few pages in SampleGrailsApp).
4.  After, changing some code(in SampleApp.js, i added alert() method to every function in that file) in  js/css files in  tomcat/webapps/SampleGrailsApp folder.
5.  Check those changes are reflecting or not in browser.
   I checked by -- opening the SampleApp in another tab  -- Not reflecting changes.
                -- Clean the browser cache  -- Not reflecting changes.
                -- Close all browsers and opened new browser  -- Not reflecting changes.
```

Comment: Don't you forget to run void cacheResources(GrailsApplication application) in BootStrap?